# BuddyPress Album plugin error. wpdb prepare was called incorrectly, it must have a placeholder

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Please, can anyone help me. The error "wpdb prepare" appears in the BuddyPress Album plugin, installed on the WordPress platform.

I searched a lot to try to solve it, but I was not successful.

Link do plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-album/

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to see the code you'd like us to assist you with. This site is for programming help, not to provide code according to a set of task requirements. Please retake the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and visit the [How to Ask pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code is the aforementioned plugin. There are many warnings in PHP. So I couldn't send. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That plugin is old. It hasn't been updated in a decade. With respect, I think you're unwise to use something that old. The $wpdb API has changed since then. What's more, the ->prepare() method is a security feature. So, your best course of action is to find a more recently maintained plugin to do the same thing.

The [source code to ->prepare()](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1395-L1513) throws a [_doing_it_wrong warning](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_doing_it_wrong/) when it detects this situation. It is a warning, not an error. If you disable WP_DEBUG, this will probably stop turning up in your logs. But that's like taking the battery out of your smoke detector.

The source code is on Github here. https://github.com/BP-Media/bp-album .

Comment: Thanks! I know it's old, but I can't find any simple and functional one like this.

buddypress lacks good gallery plugins. And the most updated plugins have bugs that prevent them from being used in my project.

The idea I have is to use this one and invest to update it in the near future.

Comment: I took a look. The required updates aren't hard. There's a fork with fixes to these obsolescences at https://github.com/OllieJones/bp-album  Now I'm trying to decide whether it's worth the trouble to petition Mika to let me take over maintenance on the plugin.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the great help
O. Jones. I don't even have words to thank you. 

  Buddypress lacks photo albums. It will be awesome if you take on the updates of this plugin.

Comment: The maintainers of the plugin accepted my pull request. I hope they will release a new version soon.   :-)

Comment: Great news! Thank you very much, O. Jones. Thank you for your help!

I have a doubt. In the version that is now in the wordpress directory, it has the possibility of pagination. For pagination to work correctly, you need to go to the file "bpa.template.tags.php" and remove the comments "//" from lines 92 to 100.

But when you uncomment the "//" lines, a warning appears: "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$domain..." appears.

Comment: We should continue this conversation using https://github.com/OllieJones/bp-album/issues

Comment: Hi, O. Jones! I posted the issue there at github.com/OllieJones/bp-album/issues